# How to get a total sum of quantity and send to the another table(Laravel)

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I want to get the total sum of quantity in `feeds` table by selecting the  `type`and `cycle_id` column in table. After that, the `inventory` table will get the sum and save.

**FeedController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
      //validate
      $this->validate($request, array(
          'date_input' => 'required|date',
          'delivery_number' => 'required|numeric',
          'type' => 'required|max:255',
          'quantity' => 'required|numeric'
      ));
      $input= Carbon::parse($request->get('date_input'));
      $cycle = Cycle::where('date_of_loading','<=',$input)
                     ->where('date_of_harvest','>=',$input)
                     ->first();

    return Feed::create([
        'date_input' => request('date_input'),
        'delivery_number' => request('delivery_number'),
        'type' => request('type'),
        'quantity' => request('quantity'),
        'cycle_id'     => $cycle->id ?? 0,
        'user_id'     => Auth::id()
    ]);
}
```

Using the `type` and `cycle_id`, the user will get the overall quantity and it will send to the `inventory` table.

```
   $overall_quantity = Feed::where('cycle_id' '=' $cycle->id ?? 0)
                           ->where('type' '=' $request->get('type'))
                           ->sum('quantity');
```

If the overall quantity does not exist to the `inventory` table, it will create a new column and if the overall quantity exists it will add to the existing overall quantity.

**inventory table**

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('type');
$table->integer('overall_quantity);
$table->unsignedInteger('cycle_id');
$table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
```

Can you help me? thanks

Comment: If not exist create new record, else update it right?

Comment: yes sir it will update

Comment: Use `return Feed::firstOrNew([` instead of `return Feed::create([`

Comment: how about the inventory table?

Comment: You want it to create/update in `Feed` OR in `inventory` table?

Comment: `inventory` table sir

Comment: Then use `firstOrNew` for `inventory` table's model instead of `Feed`

Comment: i want to get the sum of  quantity in `feed` table and send to `inventory` table and the entry in `feed` table is going to save to database

Comment: Make `$firstOrNew = Feed::firstOrNew([` and for `Inventory` make it like `return Inventory::firstOrNew([`

Comment: can you put in answer ?

Comment: i edit the question

Comment: Which column need to check in `inventory` table? Can you provide the column name?

Comment: hmm i haven't create the `inventory` table but i think it will be `id, type, quantity and cycle_id`.`feed`' will pass the `type, quantity and cycle_id` but  the `quantity` will get the overall by using  `$overall_quantity = Feed::->where('cycle_id' '=' $cycle->id ?? 0)
          ->where('type' '=' $request->get('type'))
          ->sum('quantity');`

Comment: Please check my edited answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For create or update a record, use Laravel `firstOrNew` method like:

`Feed::firstOrNew([`

To get the sum of `type` and `cycle_id` :

```
$sum = request('type') + $cycle->id;
```

Create OR update record in `Inventory` table:

```
$createOrUpdateInventory = Inventory::firstOrNew([ 
                                // Your array data to create/update
                           ]);
```

`quantity` in `feed` table:

```
$createNewFeed = Feed::create([ 
                  // Your array data you want to create
                 ]);
```

**EDIT as of your question edited:**

Retrieve quantity from inventory, or create it if it doesn't exist...

```
$inventory = Inventory::firstOrCreate(['overall_quantity' => $overall_quantity], ['type' => request('type'), 'cycle_id' => $cycle->id]);
```

For more info: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models

Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: how can i return both?

Comment: What? What you need to return? Didn't get you.

Comment: i dont need `return` to execute the queries?

Comment: If you are return to your views, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46518751/6000629 Else simply return with json response! Please read docs of Laravel basics.

Comment: yes i need to return the `feed` table so i return Feed and i just need the inventory to sum the quantity so that i can decrement it by using another table